# SciPy test failure on MacOS Mountain Lion using pip/virtualenv and XCode 4.6.3

Tags: python, macos, gcc, scipy, pip

I've had a problem running a mass spectrometry code, called nsilk, which has NumPy, SciPy and BioPython as dependencies. Since I run other Python-based projects on my Mac (Mountain Lion), I wanted to separate out virtual environments using virtualenv/pip in order to install nsilk.

Upon running the nsilk command (I've checked using 'which' that it is pointing to the version residing in the virtual environment and not a system-wide install), I receive the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/nsilk", line 32, in <module>
    import xllib
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xllib/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import MSMS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xllib/MSMS.py", line 32, in <module>
    import scipy.stats as ss
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats
```

Upon entering the (virtualenv) Python shell, if I try to import scipy.stats directly, I receive no complaint:

```
>>> import scipy.stats as ss
>>>
```

However, when I run scipy.test(), I receive a multitude of errors:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.test()
```

Here are the first three:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_logm_consistency (test_matfuncs.TestExpM)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/tests/test_matfuncs.py", line 55, in test_logm_consistency
    assert_array_almost_equal(expm(logm(a)), a)
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 387, in logm
    errest = norm(expm(F)-A,1) / norm(A,1)
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 55, in expm
    return scipy.sparse.linalg.expm(A)
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 85, in expm
    A_L1 = norm(A,1)
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py", line 116, in norm
    a = np.asarray_chkfinite(a)
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 590, in asarray_chkfinite
    "array must not contain infs or NaNs")
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

======================================================================
FAIL: test_asum (test_blas.TestFBLAS1Simple)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/lib/blas/tests/test_blas.py", line 62, in test_asum
    assert_almost_equal(f([3,-4,5]),12)
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 468, in assert_almost_equal
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError:
Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals
 ACTUAL: 0.0
 DESIRED: 12

======================================================================
FAIL: test_dot (test_blas.TestFBLAS1Simple)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/lib/blas/tests/test_blas.py", line 71, in test_dot
    assert_almost_equal(f([3,-4,5],[2,5,1]),-9)
  File "/Users/Mike/venvs/nsilk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 468, in assert_almost_equal
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError:
Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals
 ACTUAL: 0.0
 DESIRED: -9
```

I installed NumPy, SciPy and BioPython using pip, after installing XCode 4.6.3, using GCC 4.8.0 20120603 (experimental). I initially had trouble installing SciPy, as it failed on lacking a library called LibFFTPack (or similar).

Googling the error lead to the need to install a Fortran compiler for XCode. That "fixed" those tracebacks upon the compilation of SciPy when carrying out pip, but caused the above issue! I presume there is some compilation error that has created a bad install of SciPy. Might there be a mixed compiler/binary issue here?

Cheers, Mike.